# keep vibrator running in sleep mode

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to keep the vibrator run even after sleep mode (screen locks), but the app won't work.I don't know what i'm missing..

Is there any solutions other than Wake Lock,and BroadcastReceiver?

(NO prejudgements please,it's vibrate once every 4:57 minutes)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public BroadcastReceiver vibrateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                long[] pattern = {0, 3000, 297000};
                v.vibrate(pattern, 0);
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to check on how a Broadcastreceiver works.

Comment: what's should i use other than Broadcastreceiver? vibrator doesn't work with wake lock..

Comment: im not saying its the wrong approach but your code is off

Answer (score 1):

First of all create your service scheduler based on for instance alarm service. Sth. like that.

```
public class ScheduledLocalisationExecutor {

    private Context context;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private Intent broadcastIntent;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private DbxStart dbxStart;


    public ScheduledLocalisationExecutor(Context appContext) {
        context = appContext;
        dbxStart = new DbxStart();
    }

    public void setUpScheduledService(long updateTime) {
        if (dbxStart.getOpenedDatastore() == null) {
            Log.e("DROPBOX", "Dropbox account is not linked...");
            return;
        }
        Log.w("scheduled factory","updating Service!");
        broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, LocalisationUpdatesReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + updateTime, pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

Now register your broadcast receiver in android manifest.

```
 <receiver android:name=".receivers.LocalisationUpdatesReceiver">
        </receiver>
```

And create your broadcast receiver.

```
public class LocalisationUpdatesReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                long[] pattern = {0, 3000, 297000};
                v.vibrate(pattern, 0);
            }
        }
}
```

Follow that scheme and you will succeed!

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` won't execute such a long operation. You will need a service for it to run. See my answer above.

Comment: But there is no problem 'how much time' it vibrate but how to awake application, ping it to life even if screen is of please read carefully question above[first post].

Comment: I'm aware of that, but the `vibrate()` operation shouldn't be executed inside `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()`. Please check the documentation for `BroadcastReceiver` and in particular the one for `onReceive()`, it says unless the receiver is registered to run on a different thread, it will run on the main thread which will make it a candidate for being killed after about 10 secs. The docs also mention the need to associate it to a `Service` for the operation to execute properly.

Comment: Ok, I'am aware that receiver thread is good candidate to be killed after quite short time. But why we can not perform vibration thing in onReceive? If vibrations are shorter than 10sec or value that is smaller determinant to broadcast to death. But of course If your vibration stuff takes longer than that death time you should implement background operation. But as far as I know  :D vibration in most common application is shorter than 10sec and broadcast can be fired again :D but if women would like to get some way useful application :D it is sense to run it in service :D

Comment: I emphasized the usage of service because the vibration pattern provided by the OP is a continuous loop which alternates 3 secs of vibration and 4:57 of waiting. OP will probably replace it with scheduling alarms for short 3 secs long vibration patterns, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

`BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` is not designed for long operations. You should call `vibrate()` somewhere else (in a `Service` or better an `IntentService`, for that matter).

Also, the vibration pattern takes too long to run. If I was you, I'd schedule `vibrate()` to run a short pattern every 4:57 via Android's scheduling mechanism, called `AlarmManager`. The idea is, write a `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` that calls `startService(yourservice)` and schedule that BroadcastReceiver to be run each time (or better, since you will need a partial wake lock to circumvent sleep mode write a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` that calls `startWakefulService()`). Don't forget to call `YourWakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent()` at the end of your service to release the wake lock.

If you still want your service to execute a vibration pattern that runs that long, the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add the information that you can give the user a distinct and unique haptic effect by using the free haptic effect library from Immersion Corp.   That will help the user understand that this is coming from your app, and not a regular notification etc (without needing a 3 second long buzz).

That library contains 120+ fine-tuned haptic effects, and you can download it from [here](http://www2.immersion.com/developers/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=857&Itemid=957#library) with a quickstart guide to linking the library and calling it [over here](http://www2.immersion.com/developers/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=857&Itemid=957#quickstart).